# Frustrated with Simple Verilog

Tags: verilog

```
module csa_32(
    input [31:0]a,
    input [31:0]b,
    input cin,
    output [31:0]s,
    output cout 
);  

    wire [15:0]si;
    wire [31:16]s0;
    wire [31:16]s1;
    wire c;
    wire c0;
    wire c1;
    cla_16 (a[15:0],b[15:0],si,cin,c);
    cla_16 (a[31:16],b[31:16],s0,0,c0);
    cla_16 (a[31:16],b[31:16],s1,1,c1); 

    mux2_1 (s0,s1,c,sum);
    mux2_1 (c0,c1,c,cout);  
    assign s = {sum,si};
endmodule
```

I'm making a very simple carry select adder in verilog but for whatever reason it doesn't execute the code. Timing analysis shows that it takes 0 seconds and that it takes no resources. cla_16 definitely works so it's definitely something really simple I'm overlooking but I don't know what.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never declare `sum` but that shouldnt result in no resource usage, as the lower 17 bits of s and coutare calculated (sum would default to a 1-bit net). Are you getting any errors or warnings from your tool?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your modules the way you do:

```
cla_16 (a[15:0],b[15:0],si,cin,c);
```

you probably get an error: `Module or interface instance must be named` or `Missing instance name in instantiation` (depending on IDE you're using). You should name all your submodule instances, i.e.:

```
cla_16 somenamehere(a[15:0],b[15:0],si,cin,c);
cla_16 someothernamehere(a[31:16],b[31:16],s0,0,c0);
cla_16 someanothernamehere(a[31:16],b[31:16],s1,1,c1); 

mux2_1 muxnamehere(s0,s1,c,sum);
mux2_1 sndmuxnamehere(c0,c1,c,cout);
```

Comment: It compiles fine. With or without the name, the actual code just isn't executing.